# Typescript: why is a class generic not assignable to same generic inferred from `this`?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given the following code, why does Typescript error in the `getInferred` method? Is there a case where `ValueOf<this>` and `T` could be different?

```js
interface Wrapper<T> {
    value: T;
}

type ValueOf<T> = T extends Wrapper<infer U> ? U : never;

class Foo<T> implements Wrapper<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    getInferred = (): ValueOf<this> => {
        // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'GetGeneric<this>'.
        return this.value;
    }

    getSimple = (): T => {
        // Works Fine
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

For my use-case, I'm adding methods dynamically to a class and `ValueOf<this>` provides better return types for the dynamic methods.

```js
const mixin = {
    getFooInferred<Self extends Foo<any>>(this: Self) {
        return this.getInferred();
    },
    getFooSimple<Self extends Foo<any>>(this: Self) {
        return this.getSimple();
    }
}

function makeFooWithMixin<T>(value: T) {
    const foo = new Foo(value);

    Object.defineProperties(foo, {
        getFooInferred: {
            value: mixin.getFooInferred,
        },
        getFooSimple: {
            value: mixin.getFooSimple,
        }
    });

    return foo as Foo<T> & typeof mixin;
}

const foo = makeFooWithMixin("hello")

// When using the returntype of `getInferred`, we correctly get `string` as the type here
const resultInferred = foo.getFooInferred()

// When using `getSimple`, we instead get `any` because `getFooSimple` types the `Self` generic as `Foo<any>`
const resultSimple = foo.getFooSimple();
```

[Typescript playground link for all above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-nm3gdsEIFNnUEHDnOMHoZ4mEQKhMa9D0R4GukLYblu4p+kQyAAGQfDgngelBoAONya7XJ+lojmOE5Tg0s7QcUABEDRugwniSZUBqUqgMkIgqoDKo0KAtkIIgccgAAGybjKm0wGd+UooJkQEFAwcrYoZOSAkqBk3NoWlsSgMlTE4WTrlMmh6qMJlATMCifrB-7wSFaaKX0ymqVqGmGe2+LBOZ0ooKAOQQHAMwOQZVauU8l5wAqKBGXBxFpRArm6W+iIVfWrlDACQJuYZlaBoQBm+casZvkFJGWhFREkemQA)

Comment: The compiler *defers* evaluation of conditional types (like `ValueOf`) that depend on generic type parameters (and polymorphic `this` is essentially an implicit generic type parameter), so such type are essentially opaque.  You can either use a type assertion (`this.value as ValueOf<this>`), or (for this example) replace the conditional type implementation of `ValueOf` with an indexed access type, like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlvOXW).  If this addresses your question I can write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That does answer my question, @jcalz, ty! I'll mark your answer as accepted if you write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [polymorphic `this` type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) is implemented as an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter that all classes and interfaces have  (see [microsoft/TypeScript#4910](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910)).  And your `ValueOf<T>` type, defined as

```
type ValueOf<T> = T extends Wrapper<infer U> ? U : never;
```

is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  So `ValueOf<this>` is a *conditional type* that depends on a *generic type parameter*.

And unfortunately, the TypeScript compiler is unable to do much reasoning about what values will be assignable to such a type.  It *defers* evaluation of the type and can only know what it really is once `this` is specified, such as in the call `new Foo("x").getInferred()`, where `this` will be `Foo<string>`.  Inside the body of `getInferred()`, `this` is unspecified (it can be any subtype of `Foo<T>`), and so `ValueOf<this>` is essentially *opaque* to the compiler.  It isn't that `this.value` can be of a type other than `ValueOf<this>`, but rather that the compiler cannot see it.  It will reject any value that is not already of type `ValueOf<this>`.

If you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `this.value as ValueOf<this>`, then the compiler will allow you to return that, but only because you are claiming that `this.value` is of type `ValueOf<this>`, and not because the compiler can tell one way or the other:

```
getInferred = (): ValueOf<this> => {
    return this.value as ValueOf<this>; // okay
}
```

---

In general, if you need to provide a value of a generic conditional type, you'll have to do something unsafe like a type assertion.  But in this particular instance, you have an alternative.  All you're doing with `ValueOf<T>` is looking up the `value`-keyed property in `T`.  And this can be done without conditional types.  You can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) instead:

```
type ValueOf<T extends Wrapper<any>> = T['value']
```

And even though the compiler still isn't great at understanding arbitrary manipulations of generic types, it does know that if you have a value of type `T` and a key of type `K` that the property value you read at that key  will be of type `T[K]`, even if `T` or `K` are generic.  So it should be able to verify that `this.value` is of the type `this["value"]`:

```
getInferred = (): ValueOf<this> => {
    return this.value; // okay
}
```

And indeed it can.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpDYAFwjQDMFkB1NEGGagHgBUA+PI0gUgBuIADYBXCAC4knANz9SAXyKKSFAJ5skANTGSUNLrwC8spBAAeVYABMoSJizZp25GtSQBVXgH5vSDLAEELUCoRqSPCiIFAOAGIA9onGZGAwohCQlA5OrBw8fMSCJCIS0rLhkQLwicBQFGji8BSJaAAUZZIynACURSUlFAAWGFAAdF3IZlPhg0gqEcUlWBAUAJLAHmhoELZIZu29MnrlhuwjY6a8BMvzSLsU4mjASJcTU0ixuvoQ5+-cORIAD0wKQiQA1iANNVlKo7gJVhQAMoYdKZA5II49A43WElUGONoQhLkCD4wSPZ6vd6TX5zQaLASLRZEUCQWD0JAABUScQwACNMvEMJYBqRyFRaFy8i5Urd5lMegySKy7pptKcDEZOBZrBA7LlmPlXCBgBpuKZZABtADkU1tAF14TUYnEkEkUoU0RksgaKEbnAU8QjSErKi7BrV6o1mq0OuG+uL7m9Rh9fpjZhS1fMkZttrt9odjj8zkYAbjk-cqS9U2M6eUVYIc4Mkaj0dMsSXdSYQymSDWaWmG5Im8zImqlEA)